# Como fazer o teste de Hosmer-Lemeshow no R?

Tags: r

Tenho um conjunto de dados para fazer a regressão logística da variável dependente parto que é qualitativa binária.

Com o comando abaixo obtenho o modelo logístico multivariado no programa R:

```
GLM.1 <- glm(parto ~ trabalho + financiamento + consulta, family=binomial(logit), data=Dataset)
```

As variáveis independentes deste modelo também são qualitativas binárias.

Gostaria de saber qual comando do R devo usar para obter o teste de Hosmer-Lemeshow para verificar se este modelo está ajustado.

Caso seja necessário utilizar um pacote específico do R para isso, gostaria de saber qual seria este pacote e qual função usar.

Comment: Você poderia postar o seu conjunto de dados para efetuar os testes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Com uma rápida pesquisa no Stack Overflow em inglês e com o comando `RSiteSearch` do próprio `R` encontrei 2 funções para tal teste. `hoslem.test` do pacote `ResourceSelection` e `logitgof` do pacote `generalhoslem`

Comment: Usando o pacote `ResourceSelection` com o comando `hoslem.test(Dataset$parto, fitted(GLM.1))` encontro o seguinte resultado: **X-squared = 455, df = 8, p-value < 2.2e-16**. No entanto, usando o pacote `generalhoslem` com o comando `logitgof(Dataset$parto, fitted(GLM.1))` , para os mesmos dados, encontro este outro resultado: **X-squared = 4.3539, df = 7, p-value = 0.7382**. Além disso, usando o programa SPSS, também para os mesmos dados, ainda encontro outro resultado **X-squared = 4.168, df = 8, p-value = 0.842**. Você poderia me explicar porque esses resultados são diferentes?

Comment: não faço ideia por que dessa diferença. Eu utilizei o exemplo dado no `help` da função `hoslem.test` e comparei o resultado de ambas as funções, e o resultado foi o mesmo.

Comment: Segue o link (https://www.dropbox.com/s/64jo0auqeowj8fh/teste.xlsx?dl=0). Comando para gerar o modelo: `GLM.1 <- glm(parto ~ trabalho + financiamento + consulta, family=binomial(logit), data=Dataset)`. Resultados atualizados com o que obtive nos testes para as variáveis: pacote `ResourceSelection` e comando `hoslem.test(Dataset$parto, fitted(GLM.1))` encontrei **X-squared = 455, df = 8, p-value < 2.2e-16**; pacote `generalhoslem` e comando `logitgof(Dataset$parto, fitted(GLM.1))` encontrei **X-squared = 2.2901, df = 3, p-value = 0.5144**. No SPSS **X-squared = 2,357; df = 5; p-valeu = 0.798**

Comment: acabei de rodar aqui, e a diferença que apareceu aqui foi nos graus de liberdade e no p-valor do teste. `GLM.1 <- glm(parto ~ trabalho + financiamento + consulta, family=binomial(logit), data=test`. O comando `hoslem.test(GLM.1$y, fitted(GLM.1))` resultou em `X-squared = 2.2901, df = 8, p-value = 0.9708` e o resultado do comando `logitgof(GLM.1$y, fitted(GLM.1))` foi `X-squared = 2.2901, df = 3, p-value = 0.5144` com um **warning** `In logitgof(GLM.1$y, fitted(GLM.1)) : Not possible to compute 10 rows. There might be too few observations.`

Comment: Coloquei o pacote `reshape` para rodar junto com o pacote `ResourceSelection` e rodei o comando `hoslem.test(Dataset$parto, fitted(GLM.1))`. Então, o resultado agora ficou igual ao do Rafael Cunha **X-squared = 2.2901, df = 8, p-value = 0.9708**. Com o pacote `generalhoslem` e comando `logitgof(Dataset$parto, fitted(GLM.1))` o resultado continua dando **X-squared = 2.2901, df = 3, p-value = 0.5144**, e também aparece a mesma mensagem **Warning in `logitgof(Dataset$parto, fitted(GLM.1))` :
Not possible to compute 10 rows. There might be too few observations.**

Comment: Talvez essa diferença seja devido a alguma diferença na implementação dos códigos...

Answer (score 1):

O que eu sei, sobre o teste de hosmer e lemeshow que essa diferença pode ser em função do agrupamento dos dados, quando os dados não são múltiplos de dez ou da quantidade de grupo para o teste estatístico, que em geral é 10, os agrupamentos são diferente no spss e no teste do resourseselection no r. Por exemplo com 105 amostras no spss ele agrupa os 9 primeiros com 11 dados e o ultimo grupo com 6 enquanto no r com o pacote resourse selection ele tenta deixar do mesmo tamanho todos os grupos, entao alguns grupos ficarão com 11 outros com 10 amostras por grupo, o que da diferença no resultado. Particularmente nao sei identificar qual é o mais correto.